# Definition of generic class: Problems with bounds on type

Tags: java, class

I would like to do something really simple: a Rectangle class where the coordinates are either int or double. However, in the following code

```
public class Rect<T extends Number>
{
    T X1;
    T Y1;
    T X2;
    T Y2;

    public Rect(T x1, T y1, T x2, T y2)
    {
        X1 = x1;
        Y1 = y1;
        X2 = x2;
        Y2 = y2;
    }

    public Rect()
    {
        X1 = 0;
    }
}
```

I get an error message "Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T". I chose java.lang.Number as base class type because Integer and Double are in there. I also get an error when I write "X1 = new T(0)". Can anybody tell me what's wrong here? In the end, I would like to operate with the class members (addition and so on).

Comment: Indeed you have to learn more about generics.

Comment: Very helpful, really.

Comment: (additional hint: an `int` cannot be converted to a `Number`, not even through boxing). What you are most probably missing is the information that [generic types are erased at run-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). This means: a) you cannot programmatically instantiate something of a generic type and b) you cannot query any property of the generic type (e.g. `.class()` or `instanceof`).

Comment: Why don't you simplify and just get the coordinates as Double? Doesn't make much sense to me to try to get it as int or as double.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why I get these downvotes? Is the question too simple for stackoverflow? Where can I ask elsewhere if so?

Comment: Consult the documentation for [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class. Nowhere in that doc does it say you can do `Number n = 0`.

Comment: @smac89 But I can do new Number(); which doesn't work here with T.

Comment: I edited my comment

Comment: `Number` is an abstract class...

Comment: Ok, got that. Thanks

Comment: @amsmath you get those downvotes because you did not research the topic beforehand. Look e.g. at the official Java Tutorial from Oracle. We cannot recommend another platform to ask you question since off-site resources are off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Turing85 I did look at several sites, but my problem was not addressed there specifically. Well, up to now, no one here has a solution for me. Just a workaround...

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but anytime you mention getting an error message, you need to show the code which caused that error message.

Comment: You really have to ask yourself, what the benefit of having your `Rect` class have coordinates of type `AtomicInteger`, is. Just because it is called `Number` does not mean you have to use it. `Number` is just a family name given to the concrete types which extend the abstract Number class. Using a double as your coordinates would really work better. If you do have a better reason for wanting to use `Number` as a super class, then post your reasons here as an edit or ask a new question

Comment: @VGR I posted code, didn't I? It is the X1 = 0; which causes the error.

Comment: @smac89 Ok, I will use double only. I was just curious how I could possibly create such a generic class in an easy way. Obviously, it is not so easy and wouldn't pay off at last.

Comment: @amsmath normally, generics mix well with the [Inversion of Control Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). But this in return means less comfort for the end user: s/he has to instantiate some attributes beforehand and parse them to the constructor. To avoid this, one can deploy the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks so much for the link and your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should just assume that all coordinates are Double. It's better to make it simple.
Another solution is to remove the constructor where you are trying to set the values as zero. Just use the constructor where you pass all the values.

Comment: Excellent solutions

Comment: Of course I can do that. But I don't want it. I want to learn Java, so I would like to understand how to properly define generic classes. Second, I can of course leave the second constructor away. However, in the end I would like to do simple operations as addition and so on on my members X1...Y2.

Comment: The thing is you cannot assign a value if you don't know it's type. By just removing the other constructor you can still add operations to it.

Comment: @amsmath The problem with your solution is that the `Number` class is the super class of the following classes `AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short`. So any operation you want to support has to also comply with the aforementioned subclasses. This is difficult because super classes do not have much influence over their subclasses apart from ensuring that they conform to the parent's structure.

Comment: @amsmath the second solution suggested by this answer would better suit what you are after

Comment: @smac Thanks for your comment. I see. So, it is hardly possible in Java to realize what I wanted to do...?

Comment: @amsmath Not impossible. Note that the `Number` class has a method called `doubleValue()`, which means that if you use the second solution suggested by this answer, you can then make use of the `doubleValue()` method for your calculations. In other words, the first solution suggested here would have worked better in the first place

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, generics doesn't work with primitives(try passing `int`
  as a type argument to `java.util.ArrayList` and see what happens).
- Secondly, you cannot do `new T(0)` because `T` is inferred to their bound or `Object` if there is no bound at runtime. Now what happens when you do `new T(0)` is that at runtime this `T` gets inferred to `Number` and `Number` doesn't have a constructor with [arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#Number--)
  (Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html))

You can do something `X1 = new Integer(0)` or better `X1 = new Double(0.0)` if that's what you require.

Comment: "*you cannot do new `T()` because `T` isn't a class name or type name [...]*" - That is not true. `T` is a type. The problem is that generic type information are erased at run-time and replaced with their bound (or `Object`, if no bound exists).

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the suggestion. I completely overlooked this aspect and made a blunder. I was just revising generics myself this other day. I need to be more careful.